# jquery .live() with 'ready' event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to do something with all the newly added divs (with some class) in the body, but i realize the .live() method does not support 'ready' eventType.

for example, this code works:

```
$('.new').live('click', function(){
    $(this).css("background", "black");
}
```

but the user have to click on the div and i want to do the action automaticaly.

i tried this plugin: http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/announcing-jquery-live-ready-1-0-release/ but it didn't worked (action is done on the existing divs, but not on later-added ones)

Comment: how do you add 'newly added divs'?  Also, try .bind()

Comment: Why not simply make the `.css("background", "black")` call in the code that is adding the new divs?

Comment: More detail and an example posted at JSFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: i'm working with a greasemonkey script, and i'm not adding the new divs

Answer (score 1):

You really only have two options:

1. Find an appropriate event fired on the div creation that you can hook into (sounds like you can't really find a suitable one)
2. Create a timer event that hunts for new divs and then runs the code on them (this can get processor intensive depending on the scope of the DOM that you're looking at).

Example for 2.:

```
window.setInterval(function() { $('.new').css("background", "black"); } }, 100);
```

Ideally you would want to use a faster/more specific selector than `'.new'` or execute it on a cached jQuery reference to a close ancestor if the page is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you accomplish this by just using plain CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
div.new { background: #000; }
</style>
```

I guess that wouldn't work if you want to do any other kinds of affects (fade the color, jiggle the box, whatever).  In that case, I would ask - what event brings in new divs to your content?  I might try to attach the div-changing event to that, or maybe make a custom event that you fire using [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`.trigger()`.](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).